# Swipe gesture does not work in AlertDialog on Google Glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I implemented gesture detection on my app and it works well on a activity.

Now, what i want to do is to be able to use those gesture detection in an AlertDialog.
Indeed i have an activity with a Cancel button. When i click on this button, the user have to confirm his choice in an AlertDialog which have two button: Yes and No. However, in this AlertDialog, swipe gesture does not work and i am not able to choose between Yes or No because it only focus on the No button.

I want to implement Swipe gesture detection for this alert dialog. Here is what i did :

```
package com.example.recente;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;

public class ChoixUtilisateur extends Activity {


private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
Button cancelno;
Button cancelyes;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_choix_utilisateur);
    Button execute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.execute);
    execute.setFocusable(true);
    execute.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
    execute.requestFocus();

}



private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
    //Create a base listener for generic gestures

    gestureDetector.setBaseListener( new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
            Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

            AlertDialog.Builder cancelbutton = new          AlertDialog.Builder(ChoixUtilisateur.this);

            if (gesture == Gesture.TAP) {
                // do something on tap
                 if (cancel.hasFocus()){



            //              .getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
                            cancelbutton.setTitle("Confirm");  
                            cancelbutton.setMessage("Do you really want to proceed ?");  
                            cancelbutton.setPositiveButton("Yes",new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int i){
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChoixUtilisateur.this,Cancel.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });  
                            cancelbutton.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int i){
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            cancelbutton.setCancelable(false) ;
                            cancelbutton.create();  
                            AlertDialog dialog = cancelbutton.create(); 
                            cancelno = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); 
                            cancelyes = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                            cancelbutton.show();  


                }
                else{

                }



                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_TAP) {
                // do something on two finger tap
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
                // do something on right (forward) swipe


                 if(cancelno.hasFocus()){
                    cancelyes.setFocusable(true);
                    cancelyes.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
                    cancelyes.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    cancelno.setFocusable(true);
                    cancelno.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
                    cancelno.requestFocus();
                }

                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT) {
                // do something on left (backwards) swipe
                if(cancelno.hasFocus()){
                    cancelyes.setFocusable(true);
                    cancelyes.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
                    cancelyes.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    cancelno.setFocusable(true);
                    cancelno.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
                    cancelno.requestFocus();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    return gestureDetector;
}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that using alert dialog is best practice with Google Glass, use the standard cards or if you want more customization you can use simple activities.